# Google Analytics - How to call gtag on click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js, cookieconsent

I am using the [Osano Cookie Consent](https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent) plugin on my website. It displays a banner, which enables or disables tracking using google analytics, using the following code snippet:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "type": "opt-out",
    "content": {
      "message": "This website uses cookies",
      "allow": "Allow all cookies",
      "deny": "Deny all cookies"
    },
    onInitialise: function (status) {
      var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
     
      if (!didConsent) {
        gaOptout();
      }
    },
    onStatusChange: function (status, chosenBefore) {
      var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
     
      if (!didConsent) {
        gaOptout();
      }
      if (didConsent) {
        enableCookies();
      }
    }
  })});
</script>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  var gaProperty = 'UA-128681096-1';

  // Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
  var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
  if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
    window[disableStr] = true;
  }

  // Opt-out function
  function gaOptout() {
    document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
    window[disableStr] = true;
  }
  
  // Opt-in function
  function enableCookies() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments)
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
    window[disableStr] = false;
  }
</script>
```

This works as expected. However, at one place on the website I am tracking a user event, when a modal is clicked, like so:

```
<a onclick="gtag('event', 'EventName', { 'event_category': 'CV', 'event_label': 'clicked' });">
```

Clicking the link returns the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gtag' of undefined at
> HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

I guess this occurs, since the gtag function is within the enableCookies function scope. So what I tried was:

```
var outerFunction = enableCookies();
<a onclick="outerFunction.gtag('event', 'EventName', { 'event_category': 'CV', 'event_label': 'clicked' });">
```

Unfortunately that did return the same error.
I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Did you manged to include the gtag global snippet above the anchor tag you trying to send the event? refer [here](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/snippet).